# Sending result from FIND to IF in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

after receiving critics for not asking the question the right way, I have returned again with what I think is better way. I am trying to solve homework problem in which I have to write a batch file and I am stuck.

When this batch file is called in CMD it receives 4 parameters:

- (1) Path to some directory with \ at the end; example: C:\Users\PC\Desktop\
- (2) Extension of the file; example: txt
- (3) Some string; example: "ab"
- (4) An integer; example: 3

The purpose of this batch file is to find all files X with extension (2) on local directory and all subdirectories received by (1), which have more than (4) lines in them that have substring (3) and write in console next sentence:

"File X has more than (4) liens, more precise Y, which have substring (3)". Where X is full path of the file that fulfills those conditions and Y exact number of lines in which substring is found.

Input in console should be like this: myfile.bat C:\Users\PC\Desktop\ txt ab 3

My attempt of solving this was like this:

```
@echo off
for %%a in ('dir /s %1*.%2') do (
    for /f "delims= " %%G in ('find /c "%3" ^<%%a') do (
        set linecount=%%G
        if %linecount% gtr %4 (
            echo File %%a has more than %4 lines, more precisley %linecount% which have substring %3
        )
    )
)
```

Hope this time I've done it partially right.

Comment: Is the the third, _or any_, parameter doublequoted, _you're showing it in doublequotes_. I asked you the same question before you deleted the question previously but without response.

Comment: Technically, all four of the parameters are strings, but if they are, aren't, can or cannot be doublequoted is relatively important.

Comment: I have tried simple FIND command in console without quotes and it said that parameter format is not correct.

Comment: If `%3` is `"ab"` then `Find /C ""ab""` would not be the same as `Find /C "ab"`, if you see what I'm getting at. Similarly, if the directory was passed as `C:\Program Files` then `%1` would resolve to `C:\Program`, `%2` as `Files`, `%3` as `txt` and the expected integer would be `ab`, that would very likely not be what you'd want to happen. These things can be worked around, but the easiest way would be to verify that the input parameters are valid for processing as the opening task.

Comment: Yes I see. That problem I can solve, but I still don't see how solve the IF statement. I have some experience with C/C++ and I would use local variable to store the value from the FIND /c, and than use it in IF and later in echo for Y. But I have only 2 days of experience with CMD so this quite confusing for me, and professor said that we cant **use set var=**

Comment: You need to capture the output of the `FIND` command with a `FOR /F` command. `FOR /F "delims=" %%G in ('find /c "%3" ^<%%a') DO SET linecount=%%G`.

Comment: I have edited code, was that what you meant ?

Comment: You actually do not need to set the `FOR` variable to an environmental variable.  Just use the `FOR` variable directly.  If you don't use the `FOR` variable directly then you need to enable delayed expansion and reference the environmental variable accordingly.

Comment: Your task appears to be to recursively search **`"%~1"`** for **`*.%2`** files retrieving those whose contents have more than **`%4`** lines containing the string **`%~3`**. You need to clarify the string match, **`ab`**; some of these may contain a match for you: **`music by Abba`**, **`cAbBaGe`**, **`drug abuse`**, **`FleaBag`**, **`kebab night`**, **`label`**, **`match ab in`**, **`search WAB for`**, **`string AB found`**, but which?

Comment: It is as you said, that is the point of this batch, for matching string I'll add  /I so it is not case sensitive. But I didn't quite get what  Squashman has told me replace in my code. When I run the code from above with same parameters it says that  **3 was unexpected this time**.

Comment: You might want to add `dir` switch `/b` (see `dir /?`). Also your outer `for` is wrong. See `for /?`. Compo already told you what's the reason for `3 was unexpected..`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question parameters to date, *and just for the hell of it*, here's a one line batch file solution, *(with very limited testing)*:

```bat
@For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir/B/S/A-D-S-L "%~1*.%2"') Do @For /F "Tokens=3Delims=:" %%B In ('Find /I /C "%~3" "%%A"') Do @If %%B Gtr %4 Echo File %%A has more than %4 lines, more precisley%%B, which have substring %3
```

This one uses the `Where` command, *(which I prefer because it will not work with trailing backslashes tagged to directory names)*:

```bat
@For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where/R "%~1" *.%2') Do @For /F "Tokens=3Delims=:" %%B In ('Find /I /C "%~3" "%%A"') Do @If %%B Gtr %4 Echo File %%A has more than %4 lines, more precisley%%B, which have substring %3
```

Comment: They both work, but I like the second more, because it didn't make any problems with backslash. The first as you said made that problem at first: The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: @Yoshi, thats why I prefer it because file and directory names cannot contain the backslash character it is a just path separator. When there's nothing to separate, it shouldn't be there!

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b "%1*.%2"') do (
    for /f "delims=: tokens=3" %%g in ('find /c "%3" "%%a"') do (
        set linecount=%%g
        if !linecount! gtr %4 (
            echo File %%a has more than %4 lines, more precisley !linecount! which have substring %3
        )
    )
)
```

Big thanks to all for making this possible.

Comment: FYI, you can change line `6` to `if %%g gtr %4 (`, change `!linecount!` on line `7` to `%%g` then remove lines `2` and line `5` completely.