# If command in cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file

i'm working in cmd and i need a little help. I want to modify this code (which is working) :

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('findstr /s /m %3 "%1*.%2"') do (
findstr /S /R /N "^" "%%a" | find /C ":"
)
```

So, this code has 3 parameters (1.path, 2.extension and 3. string) and only searches for files that contain that string. The search is conducted in the directory sent as parameter and all the subfolders. This code will show how many lines each file has only if the file contains the string sent as parameter.
Now i want to modify this code in a way that i can send 4th parameter which is a number, and i want it to (obviously echo YES!) only if the number of lines in file is greater than the number sent as parameter. However, my code down below isn't working (i have tried many solutions which includes ( [ " ' etc. ) but i can't get it to work.

```
 @echo off
for /f %%a in ('findstr /s /m %3 "%1*.%2"') do (
if findstr /S /R /N "^" "%%a" | find /C ":" gtr %4 echo YES!
)
```

Can you help me? :)

Comment: Looks like you are trying to do the same thing as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50053247/sending-result-from-find-to-if-in-cmd) I answered yesterday. They pretty much look identical to me.  Which means you two are students taking the same class.

Comment: That surely is one of my classmates. I'm surprised that his question didn't come up when i searched for answers. However copying this would be cheating so i will try to find another solution since our codes are slightly different :)  can you at least tell me can i pass command1 | command2 in IF statement?

Comment: The /s parameter in your second findstr is redundant. Why not use a single `findstr /S /N` and parse the output with `for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:"` and store the highest line number per file in the environment?

Comment: @Jupiter, don't copy your classmates answer, copy mine, I'll replicate it here over a few lines instead of one.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still trying to do it though, i feel like i'm so close :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, made to look a little different.

This includes filters to prevent the `Dir` command from reading directories, system files and reparse points too:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%A IN ('DIR /B /S /A:-D-S-L "%~1*.%2"') DO (
    FOR /F "TOKENS=3 DELIMS=:" %%B IN ('FIND /I /C "%~3" "%%A"') DO (
        IF %%B GTR %4 (
            ECHO File %%A has more than %4 lines matching the string %3, it has%%B.
        )
    )
)
```

---

This uses `FindStr` as in your example, but it's a little slower:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%A IN ('FINDSTR /S /M /I /C:"%~3" "%~1*.%2"') DO (
    FOR /F "TOKENS=3 DELIMS=:" %%B IN ('FIND /I /C "%~3" "%%A"') DO (
        IF %%B GTR %4 (
            ECHO File %%A has more than %4 lines matching the string %3, it has%%B.
        )
    )
)
```

*(Remember that the script was designed to accept specific format and order of input parameters)*.